# How to install bcmath on a debian:jessie php5.6?

Tags: docker, php-5.6, debian-jessie, bcmath

I am running a linux instance on a [docker container](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/bfe27759103fa6050601060165409b5b3be06395/5.6/jessie/apache/Dockerfile). It is a debian:jessie with a php 5.6.

I want to install **bcmath** module, but I have no success.

Does someone know how o do that?

```
root@1419c032c35f:/etc/php5/fpm# apt install php5.6-bcmath
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5.6-bcmath
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-bcmath'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply create a Dockerfile that will build from the image you want (the one linked above) and add the line

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
```

Comment: Perfect, bcmath is enabled now.

Comment: This solution also works for php:7.2-apache-stretch image using Alpine Linux.